# HOw do I file a police report and still ensure the FBI doesn't get involved?

Tags: fraud

I work for a company who's checks have been fraudulently copied and used in a scam.  I'd like to report this to my local PD, but I'm concerned they'll get the FBI involved.  As I understand it, once the FBI gets involved, their investigation becomes very invasive and would put a tremendous strain on our organization.  I just want to file a police report and that's it.  How do I do that?  Thoughts?

Comment: The government does what the hell it wants. If you file a report, if they're interested they will get involved. That said, check fraud is serious. If it's part of a bigger scam you will want to report it and hope they get involved.

Comment: This question is not about IT Security.

Comment: If you're that concerned about what might be discovered during the course of a federal investigation then you need to consult an attorney, not SO.

Comment: Not only is it not about IT security, it is also primarily opinion-based, so it would probably not fit in Law.SE . That being said, I second @Johnny's advice: consult an attorney.

Answer (score 1):

**Hire an attorney.** It sounds like you want to help the police catch the person but limit the scope and impact of an investigation. Attorneys can help you with this.

Likewise an attorney can advise you about what is most likely to happen. You may find out that you actually have nothing to worry about and that this might be easier than you think. In any case, it's not uncommon for attorneys to have an initial discussion for free so you have very little risk in that initial discussion and are very likely to learn about how this is handled in your jurisdiction.

Long-term: Learn how to make it cheaper and easier for your company to deal with discovery requests. Odds are as your business continues to operate you are at increasing odds of eventually running into a need to handle a discovery request. If you plan for it this can be a trivial process with low impact to your team. Not planning for it is what makes it painful.